Finding value of unknown coefficient such that a linear system has a number of solutions
For which value/s of $a$ will the linear system have a unique, infinite, and no solution?
$\begin{cases} 2x+y+3z=1\\ x+2y+2z=2 \\ 3x+3y+az=3\end{cases}$
By Gaussian Elimination
$$
\left[
\begin{array}{@{}ccc|c@{}}
4a-20&0&2 & 0 \\
0& \ 6a-30& \ 0 & \ 6a-30\\
0&0& 2a-10 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$
The system will have infinite number of solutions if $a$ makes the last row all zeroes.  $2a -10 \ = 0$. So, for $a = 5$, it will have an infinite number of solutions.
The system will have no solutions if $2a -10 \neq 0$. So, for $a \neq 5$ it will have  no solutions.
But I cannot find the value for which the system will have a unique solution?
I considered the system in $AX = b$ matrix form and found the determinant of A, which is $3a-15$. If the determinant is not $0$ , then A is invertible, which means the system has a unique solution. So, for  $3a -15 \neq 0$ or if $a \neq 5$, the system has a unique solution. BUT, I found out earlier that,for $a \neq 5$ it will have  no solutions??

The system will have no solutions if $2a -10 \neq 0$ - this is wrong. The last line only represents the equation $(2a-10)z=0$. Then we just have $z=0$, which gives a solution, namley $(x,y,z)=(0,1,0)$.

Here is a bit of an unconventional approach, but I think it works nicely here:
Take the first two equations and transpose them:
$2x+y=1-3z$ $(1)$
$x+2y=2-2z$ $(2)$
Now, solve these for $x$ and $y$ in terms of $z$: $x=\frac{-4z}{3},y=\frac{-z+3}{3}$.
Substitute into the third equation to obtain $-4z-z+3+az=3$
Which becomes $(a-5)z=0$.
If $a=5$ there is no unique solution.
If $a\neq 5$ then $z=0$ which means $x=0$ and $y=1$ which is a unique solution.
